# Why height is not stable when I put my control in the panel?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, panel

I have a textbox and adjusted a `height` with CSS for it. When I put it in the `Panel`, its `height` returns to the previous `height`. How can I fix it? In other word how to keep its `height` stable?

My HTML code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelPost" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtNumPost" CssClass="TxtNamePost" runat="server">           </asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
```

My CSS code:

```
.TxtNamePost {
     Height: 30%;
}
```

It should be noted that `height: 30px` works correctly, But I need to do that using `%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have two things going on.

1. height: 30%. In css, if you display a height in percentage, it will be percentage of the parent element. So if you move an element around (inside a panel for example). you are changing the parent element and that could lead to confusion.
2. .NET will change the id of your textbox once you move it inside the panel. Click 'View Source' on your page to see what the new ID is. It could be something like 'panelPost_TxtNumPost'. Or better yet, set the 'ClientIDMode=static' on the Textbox to avoid what I just mentioned.